# Override Wordpress POST REST API

Tags: rest-api

I use the REST API to create post and taxonomy remotely in a Wordpress website.

It works perfectly for classical fields but i need to send some custom fields, and there are not interpreted by Wordpress.

1. In post a need to fill up the fields _yoast_wpseo_primary_post (that is a fields added by yoast) and force to set up a translation post (WPML)
2. In taxonomy i need to fill up fields added by ACF (it works for post, but not for taxonomy)

I'm wondering if it's not possible to override Worpdress to be able to manage any fields i want ? Is there a function or hook to do this when i post via API ?
(i'm a beginner with API in wordpress)

Thanks

Comment: I looks like you need to add custom endpoints. [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/)